# Calling a Method from Within a Ruby Class? (or is this rails magic)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

I'm new to Ruby and working through some tutorials/screencasts.  I've reached the section where they're discusisng the `before_filter` callback, and it's using some syntax that's a little weird for me.  I don't know if it's a feature of ruby, of if it's some rails magic, and was hoping someone here could set me straight or point me in the right direction w/r/t the manual

This is a code fragment from the screencast I'm watching

```
class MachinesController < ApplicationController
    #...
    before_filter :login_required, :only => [:report]
    #...    
    def index
        #etc...
    end

    def login_required
        #etc...
    end
end
```

In the context of rails, I understand that `before_filter` is a callback that will fire `login_required` method when the `report` action is called.  However, it's not clear to me what it is within the context of ruby.  In other languages classes typically contain methods, properties, class variables and constants defined within the braces.

However, this looks like its a function call inside the class, and some experiments have show that you can put code in your class definitions and have it called when the program runs.   Is this correct?  If so, are there special contextual rules for code that's put inline into a class like that? (i.e. would the before_filter function in rails know what class it was called from)  If not, what magic is rails doing here?

Comment: IMO you should choose Sarah Mei's answer as your 'selected answer', it provides the best and most complete explanation.

Comment: Sarah's answer is great, but it's to a question I didn't ask.  I was confused by the calling of methods inside of a class, something you can't do in PHP or Java.  I wanted to know if that was some rails magic, or if ruby supported that, and if Ruby supported that, what was different w/r/t calling code from within a class.  Jonathan answered that, explaining how self changed identity.

Comment: Perhaps the question should be edited a bit, I was thinking something like: "Ruby: Calling a Function from within a Class definition"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`before_filter` is a not actually a callback. It's a [class method of `ActiveRecord::Base`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods) that sets up a callback when you call it. So in this example:

```
before_filter :login_required, :only => [:report]
```

When the class is loaded, the method is called, and it adds `:login_required` to the filter chain for the `report` method.

The convention for these types of calls is to drop parens, but it would work just fine (and would be more easily identifiable as a method call) if you did this:

```
before_filter(:login_required, :only => [:report])
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike in some other languages, in Ruby the class can be modified at runtime and you can make function calls from within the class definition. So what's happening in this case is that you are calling the `before_filter` function, which then modifies the `MachinesController` class definition at runtime.

This is the mechanism which allows for the strikingly beautiful (to my eyes, at least) syntax that you get with Rails where it almost looks like you're using some sort of Domain Specific Language to describe your models. Stuff like the `validates`, `has_many` and `belongs_to` function calls on model classes.

My understanding is that this is called a macro and falls under the umbrella of meta programming. You can [read more about this topic](http://www.vitarara.org/cms/ruby_metaprogamming_declaratively_adding_methods_to_a_class).

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is so cool. You can definitely send messages from within a class block. As I understand it, what things like `class` do, other than the obvious, is control the identity of `self`. Thus, you should be able to call any method of the class or included modules from there.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't encountered the self keyword yet or learned how to define static/class methods. This makes a lot more sense now (but is still hugely weird)

Comment: You cannot invoke a method defined on an 'included module' from within a class definition. In order to invoke a method provided by a module within the class definition the module must be `extend`ed not `include`d in the class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your question is, but here's my interpretation:

```
before_filter
```

This is a class method call see [ActionController](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html)

```
:login_required
```

This is a parameter to the before_filter method, and used as a callback using [Object#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000332)

```
:only => [:report]
```

This is an additional Hash parameter to before_filter see [ActionController](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Filters/ClassMethods.html) again.

I'd also suggest looking at the implementation of the before_filter method for insight.

Comment: My question/confusion is centered around the fact that you're running code other than assignments or method definitions from within a class block.  You can't do that in languages like Java or PHP and I'm looking for an explanation/tutorial on how code running from withing a class (not a class method) differs from code running outside a class definition.

Comment: Heh, I just realized that's something I've always taken for granted and never questioned. Now, I'm curious and trying to find the explanation myself. You should update your question to make it a little clearer what you need, your comment was clear - the question not.

Comment: @Alan: It doesn't. That's the beauty of it. Class bodies are just executable code, just like method bodies or script bodies. They even return a value (the return value of the last expression evaluated inside the class body, again, just like method bodies). IOW: a class "definition" isn't a class *definition*, it's a *script*, which *creates* a class definition. This allows such beautiful things as `if OS == :win then def foo; this_way end else def foo; another_way end end`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense Jörg, its just a different way of thinking about your code when you're coming from a more boring/traditional space.